# Resize/Scaling SVG image

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, mfc

My requirement is to load image from SVG file, resize it to smaller/bigger image and save it in same file.

I need to achieve this in C++ using GdiPlus or MFC or Win32 API or Microsoft's C++ libraries?

I should not use any third party libraries.

I googled but I could not get any samples.

I am able to resize WMF file using GdiPlus. Is it possible to convert SVG file to WMF file and vice-versa using GdiPlus or MFC or Win32 API or Microsoft's C++ libraries?

Comment: SVG is just an XML-based format. So you can use **MSXML** parser to read it. After that you just need to change the `viewBox` attribute. That's it

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. Generally how to display/view SVG file in MFC controls? After changing the viewbox attribute how to save it as a .svg file?

Comment: 1. To display SVG in MFC just use `CHtmlView` class. 2. MSXML is capable of loading and saving XML DOM document.

Comment: I know for sure that GdiPlus supports EMF/WMF vector graphics out of the box. I have no idea if it does support SVG or not. So you'll have to test it out. There is `CImage` class in MFC which is basically a GDI+ wrapper for images.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I checked out but the GDI+ CImage constructor is not loading SVG file.Is it possible to convert SVG file to WMF file using C++ APIs?

Comment: No there is no standard way of doing it. You'll have to use third party library or IE engine wrapped in `CHtmlView` to display SVG.

Comment: Take a look at http://svgpp.org/ It is header only C++ library which uses GDI+ to render SVG.

Answer (score 1):

SVG is just an XML-based format. So you can use **MSXML** parser to read it. The MSXML parser is capable of reading/writing any XML DOM document. After that you just need to change the `viewBox` attribute of SVG document.

The GDI+ supports EMF/WMF vector formats only and does not support rendering of SVG out of the box. So you'll have to use 3rd party libraries like http://svgpp.org. This header-only library works with **RapidXML** parser to read/write SVG and GDI+ to render it.

You can also use `CHtmlView` class to display SVG. The `CHtmlView` is basically a wrapper class around IE COM object.

Comment: svgpp is parsing the SVG file and converting SVG file to GDI+ object to render it so after parsing the SVG file using MSXML parser how to convert it to GDI+ object without using third party library.